# Block incoming traffic except a few ports and redirects

Tags: iptables

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
```

I reset iptables with the following commands:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

I want to redirect traffic destined for port 80 to 1337. These commands accomplish that:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1337
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1337
```

I continue with the following commands in order to block all incoming traffic except SSH and I expect the port redirection still works:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

But the port redirection no longer works.

Adding `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` before `iptables -A input -j DROP` doesn't make it work either.

What else do I need to add or change?

Comment: Ah. It turns out that if I add `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT` before `iptables -A input -j DROP`, the port redirection works. But I don't want to allow direct traffic to port 1337.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent direct traffic on 1337 you could do:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1/8 --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT` so only traffic from the host itself (which is the redirect) will be accepted.

Comment: Just tried what you suggested with `iptables -R INPUT` on the rule. I couldn't even connect to port 80.